# Who is the daughter of Surya mentioned in Rig Veda 10.85?

Tags: rig-veda, marriage, surya, vedic-gods, chandra

The **[Rig Veda Book 10 Verse 85](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10085.htm)** describes the bridal of Sun-god's daughter who is called Surya as well:

> 6 Raibhi was her dear bridal friend, and Narasamsi led her home.
>   **Lovely was Sūrya's robe:** she came to that which Gatha had adorned.
>
> 7 Thought was the pillow of her couch, sight was the unguent for her eyes:
>   Her treasury was earth and heaven ẉhen Sūrya went unto her Lord.
>
> 8 Hymns were the cross-bars of the pole, Kurira-metre decked the car:
>   The bridesmen were the Aśvin Pair Agni was leader of the train.
>
> 9 **Soma was he who wooed the maid: the groomsmen were both Aśvins, when
>   The Sun-God Savitar bestowed his willing Sūrya on her Lord.**

As far as I am aware the sun-god had two daughters Yami & Tapti but I haven't read of them having any association with Soma. So **I want to know who the sun-god's daughter was whose marriage is being talked about here?**

Comment: **"Suryaa (सूर्या) "is the name of the daughter of Sun god .** The two names looks identical because the original sanskrit word for the sun is "surya" (सूर्य) , but in english we pronounce it as Surya (सूर्या) and both spellings are same. She is one of the goddess of Rig-Veda.Will post the answer if more info about her is found.

Comment: Ya I thought that may be the case but haven't found her mentioned anywhere else hence the query.

Comment: It's quite possible that this Surya goddess is another name of goddess Savitri and the name Surya is just to denote that she is daughter of Surya (Savitar)  ,and possibly not a actual name.

Comment: Yes but Surya has only two daughters mentioned Yami or Yamuna and Tapti. Neither of them was married to Soma hence my question.

Comment: "Surya has only two daughters" - No, he had one more daughter named Bhadra...and may be few more... @Dr.VineetAggarwal

Comment: Hmmm do share the scriptural reference

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal  This famous hymn RV.10.85 is the detailed description of marriage between Surya and Aswin brothers(twin),not Soma. Read carefully  the verse 9 you have provided here, yourself. I need not answer it in detail as you may again accuse me for imposing my own interpretation.

Comment: @B.N.Bhaskar it says Soma is the one who wooed the maiden so it would seem that Ashwins who are mentioned as both bridesmen and groomsmen participated in the wedding representing both the parties. And even If there is a different interpretation still the question remains about who this daughter was.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Surya is the name of bride

Comment: @B.N.Bhaskar that is quite well established since the hymn itself is called Surya's bridal! The question is not about her name rather her life story as the daughter of the sun-god.

Answer (score 5):

There can be a meaning that this marriage is not a physical marriage but it symbolizes some non- materialistic meaning. This verse  can be of astrological significance, here sun might have been signified as soul(atma) and moon as mind(mann) because hindu weddings are considered to be an auspicious ritiual. So it can ressemble manno-atma sangam. This  can be of inner meanings rather than speculatives.Most of the vedic hymns are of non materialistic and inner spritual meanings so there can be a possiblity of being so. Here actually in this verse there is no mension of surya's daughter the verse just says " savitar bestowed his loving surya unto her lord". Here savitar and surya are same abstracts the only difference is savitar represents the diety and surya is non different energy from savitar. So surya here might not be the daughter of savitar. but they are actualy same energy. They represents same relation that exists between chandra and soma. So when we consider the diety for ritual purposes we call it soma and chandra when we consider it for astronomical significane. For example when i say i gave my hand to someone it does not mean my hand is a different object from me. So here savitar and surya are part of same eneegy we can say surya is part of savitars energy or just another name of savitar.

Comment: The marriage is indeed symbolic. Here SuryA stands for the "illumined Knowledge" and Soma for the "Delight of existence". I have a book on Rigveda that discusses this but the way the question is poised I can't write that as an answer.

Comment: Yes there's always a deeper meaning to most Vedic verses and this can apply here as well. But then they could have also mentioned sun or moon as a female and my question seeks to understand why Surya's daughter is mentioned.

Comment: Sir i can exactly not anwer your question but i can give you many logics to relate your question. I have stated my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mention of Sūrya's daughter marriage in RV 3.53.15 “The daughter of Sūrya given by Jamadagni gliding everywhere and dissipating ignorance, has emitted a mighty (sound), and has diffused ambrosial imperishable food among the gods.”

Is this verse also associated with RV 10.85? Rather, I am asking a question here. Probably, both the verses from different mandalas are dominated by Ashwins relates to Sūrya. The names don't appear in these verses so can we connect this daughter with Yami and Tapti.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Hindusim SE. If you're asking a question I'd recommend you to use the 'Ask Question' tab rather than using answers.

Comment: Given by Jamdagni is very suggestive of a physical object since he is credited to have tried to stop the intense heat of Surya with his arrows. In return Surya gifted him an umbrella and slippers to protect from the heat!